# How to re-order and animate text in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, jquery-animate

**Firstly, I've made a [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/matthewharwood/pen/ltCry) or [jsfiddles](http://jsfiddle.net/ebRVb/)**

---

**Background:**

Ok I have a `span` tag within a few header tags `h1,h2,h3`.  Inside that spantag is the word

**experience** *which is spelled backwards like so:*

```
<h3>for <span class="hover-spell">ecneirepxe</span>.</h3>
```

**Question**

I'm unsure on the best way to approch this but I would like on hover:

- reorder to spell experience correctly
- if possible animate them overlapping another while re-ordering

---

I have no idea how to do this but I keep thinking regex, with arrays but this feels overly complicated and I really don't know anything about regex and proper array sorting.  Any information to lead me in the right direction would be most appreciated.  Or an edit to the [codepen](http://codepen.io/matthewharwood/pen/ltCry) or [jsfiddles](http://jsfiddle.net/ebRVb/) would be so excellent.

Comment: Anything i can think of is wrapping each letter in a container so you can manipulate their positions. Getting letters from string in JS is actually straightforward - as strings are arrays - just do `var theString = 'ASD'; console.log(theString[2])` and you'll get `S`. Number of letters in a string is in `theString.length`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution is to use css to accomplish this. This solution doesn't animate the transition, it just changes the order of the letters. Add this to your css:

```
.hover-spell:hover{
    direction: rtl; 
    unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
}
```

**Edit**: Thanks to Marcel Gwerder for pointing out that [it's not possible to animate the direction property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties)

I found [this answer, in another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16700293/2240695) (it goes through a given string of text and wraps each character in a span then assigns transiton styles to each), that may help with a jquery solution.

Comment: Plus one for cleverness but damn any idea on how to get to get this to animate?

Comment: @MatthewHarwood you will not get animation with this css solution, because [it's not possible to animate the direction property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties)

Answer (score 1):

I've just tried to set up something animated with jquery, it's a bit tricky to get a fancy looking animation. But that one doesn't look too bad ([**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ebRVb/15/)).

```
var expElem = $(".hover-spell");
var exp = expElem.text();
var run = false;

expElem.empty();
for(var i = 0; i <= exp.length; i++) {
   expElem.append('<span>'+exp.charAt(i)+'</span>'); 
}

expElem.mouseover(function() {   
    if(run === true) return false;
    run = true;
    var stepDuration = 300;
    var counter = 0;

    (function anim(){
        if(counter == exp.length -1) return false; //Remove -1 to get last "e" animated
         counter++;

        var nth = exp.length;
        var elem = $('span:nth-child('+nth+')', expElem); 

        elem.slideUp(stepDuration, function() {
            (function() {
                if(counter == 1) return elem.prependTo(expElem);
                else return elem.insertAfter($('span:nth-child('+(counter-1)+')', expElem));
            })().slideDown(stepDuration, anim);
        });
    })();   
});
```

To get it working with hover(including mouseleave) is a bit more complicated. You could also try something with storing the position and then slide them over each other but again a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

```
<span id = "spell">olleh</span>   //hello in reverse

<script type="text/javascript">
        var newText;
        var text = null;
        text = document.getElementById("spell").innerHTML;
        for (var i = text.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {




            if (i == text.length - 1) {
                newText = text.substr(i, 1);
            }
            else {
                newText = newText + text.substr(i, 1);
            }
         }
        alert(newText);
    </script>
```

write this script in body tag...